# Let $f$ be a function from a topological subspace $A$ of $X$ to a Hausdorff space $Y$.

Tags: general-topology

Let $f$ be a function from a topological subspace $A$ of $X$ to a Hausdorff space $Y$. Then there exists at most one continuous extension from $\bar{A}$ (closure of $A$) to $Y$.

Problem is if $X$ is first countable then we can construct a sequence $\{x_n\}\to a$ in $\bar{A}$, then also there is no guarantee that $\{f(x_n)\}$ will converge so what will be the step?

Comment: Sequential continuity is not equivalent to continuity (in this context; you don't know if the spaces are first-countable).  Use the open-set definition of continuity instead.

Comment: The problem says "atmost", so you only have to show that if you have two extensions $e,e':\overline A\to Y$ of $f:A\to Y$, then $e=e'$.

Comment: Yeah but how to show that?

Comment: I know that I have to use open-set definition but what is the step?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Suppose that $g$ and $h$ are continuous extensions of $f$ to $\operatorname{cl}A$; you need to show that $g=h$. If not, there is some point $x\in\operatorname{cl}A$ such that $g(x)\ne h(x)$. $Y$ is Hausdorff, so there are disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ in $Y$ such that $g(x)\in U$ and $h(x)\in V$. Now consider the sets $g^{-1}[U]$ and $h^{-1}[V]$: $g$ and $h$ are continuous, so both are open nbhds of $x$ in $\operatorname{cl}A$. Use the facts that $g\upharpoonright A=f=h\upharpoonright A$ and $U\cap V=\varnothing$ to get a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify: if $a$ is in the closure of $A$ and $x_n$ converges to $a$ then it is true that $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(a)$ if $f$ is continuous - this does not require any additional assumption, and it is enough to prove that any two continuous functions which agree on $A$ also agree on the closure of $A$ (assuming $Y$ is Hausdorff, so that limits are unique).  The problem is that one can construct an example of a topological space $X$, a subset $A$, and a point $a$ in the closure of $A$ such that no sequence of points in $A$ converges to $a$.  So you cannot use sequences to prove anything about $f(a)$.  The space $X$ is necessarily not first countable (in particular, not metrizable).

Nevertheless, what you want to prove is still true.  One approach is to use nets instead of sequences.  Another approach: Assume that $f$ and $g$ are two functions on the closure of $A$ which disagree at a point $a$ in the boundary.  Since $Y$ is Hausdorff, there are disjoint neighborhoods which separate $f(a)$ and $g(a)$; pull these neighborhoods back to $X$ and try to produce a point in $A$ where $f$ and $g$ differ.

Comment: Objection with the line "Just to clarify: if a is in the closure of A and xn converges to a then it is true that f(xn) converges to f(a) if f is continuous - this does not require any additional assumption"--this is not true when the function is from A to Y. This true when f is from X to Y. Here u have define f(a).

Comment: And How do I use nets?

Comment: @user152715: as something of an aside: this seems like it is a homework question.  If it, then you probably shouldn't try to learn and use nets unless they are already appearing in your course.

Comment: Yeah I have done it. guy-in-seoul

Answer (score 0):

You want to show that “at most one” extension exists; however there may be none, so you don't need to build the extension.

Hint: if $f\colon A\to B$ and $g\colon A\to B$ are continuous maps of topological spaces (with $B$ Hausdorff) and $\{x\in A:f(x)=g(x)\}$ is dense in $A$, then $f=g$.